# For loop inside a for loop - to grab names from a json array

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, json, for-loop

I have a container that has rows with 4 columns each.  I am trying to use a for loop to grab each columns title with ajax from a json array.  I was able to do this fine for one row with one for loop.

```
var i = 0;
var z = 1;

for(z; z < 35; i++, z++) {
    var ingredientLocation = '.row div:nth-child(' + z + ') .inner-rec-box h1';        
    $(ingredientLocation).text(this[0].children[i].categoryName);
}
```

This loop just gives each row the first 4 results from the loop rather then continuing to the next row.

I have 4 - 5 rows that I want this loop to send titles too so I tried adding a second loop inside the first to essentially go into the first row loop through the first 4 titles then leave the inner loop and jump to the second row continue looping the i value where it had left off and so on. Below is my attempt at this

```
var z = 1;
var i = 0;

for(z; z < 5; z++) {
    var ingredientLocation = '.conatiner .row:nth-child(' + z + ') .inner-rec-box h1';
    for(i; i < 5; i++){
        $(ingredientLocation).text(this[0].children[i].categoryName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please format your code when posting a question.Thanks @BrianGlaz

Answer (score 2):

You have to reset your inner index in each time you start the inner loop

```
var z;
var i;

for (z = 0; z < 5; z++) {    
    var ingredientLocation = '.conatiner .row:nth-child(' + z + ') .inner-rec-box h1';    
    // set i to 0 when starting a row
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      $(ingredientLocation).text(this[0].children[i].categoryName);
    }   
}
```